# Simple Java GUI, cards not appearing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, imageicon

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlideShow {
    JFrame slide = new JFrame("Slide Show");

    public SlideShow(){
        slide.setSize(300,400);
        slide.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        slide.setVisible(true);
        slide.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Images/picture1"));
        panel.add(label);
        slide.add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SlideShow slide = new SlideShow();

    }
}
```

I have to create a simple Java GUI that displays some cards. First, I just wanted to test it by displaying one card. For some reason I can't seem to figure out why nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Can you share where your image is located? Does it not have a file extension?

Comment: I'm using eclipse, my images are located in an Images folder within the project folder.

Comment: You aren't getting any errors, right?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. Is there any other way I can add an image from a filepath?

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually used a proper file name `"Images/picture1"`. Should be something like `"Images/picture1.png"` with the file format

Also image files, generally should be read from the class path, if you plan on having them embedded to the program.  To do so, you will first need to put the file in the class path. With most IDE build configurations it's as simple as placing the image in the `src`. So

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            images
                  picture1.png
```

Then you would read it like

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/picture1.png"));
```

A better approach would be to use `ImageIO.read()`. If the file path is incorrect, it will throw an exception, so you know where you're going wrong

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/picture1.png"));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

You will need to put it in the `try/catch` block

Also do what codeNinja said about the `setVisible()` *after* adding component. Also preferably `pack()` the frame, instead of `setSize()`

Comment: I agree but wouldn't they have gotten a `FileNotFoundException` if they were missing the extension?

Comment: @codeNinja The [`String` based constructor for `ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-) does not throw any exceptions, which is one reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Frame visible after you add all necessary components to it. Move `slide.setVisible(true);` Down to the bottom of the constructor like this:

```
...
slide.add(panel);
slide.setVisible(true);
```

Alternatively you can add `slide.revalidate();` at the bottom of your constructor.

Comment: You should mention that revalidating after adding components also solves these situations. Even though setting visible at a later time will fix the situation, its always good to know how to add components even if the parent is already visible

Comment: I tried this, It's still not working for me. I have other programs where setVisible(true) isnt on the bottom, and the SAME pictures are shown.

Comment: *"I have other programs where setVisible(true) isnt on the bottom, and the SAME pictures are shown."*  That doesn't make them right.  `setVisible` should be last.